# Getting rotation degree from gyroscope android sensor

Tags: android, android-sensors, gyroscope

Ive searched the internet thin so far.
I am trying to develop a problem where i need the degrees of rotation from the phones starting point. To know if the users it moving the phone up or down i am using the accelerometer, which in start was a bit unstable, but however i managed to make it stable.
I now need the the degree of rotation around it self. Like the orientation sensor, which is deprecated. I then tryid using the Magnometer, but i was way to unstable.
I then determed that i wanted to try using the gyroscope, when i use the sample code:

```
 // This timestep's delta rotation to be multiplied by the current rotation
 // after computing it from the gyro sample data.
 if (timestamp != 0) {
     final float dT = (event.timestamp - timestamp) * NS2S;
     // Axis of the rotation sample, not normalized yet.
     float axisX = event.values[0];
     float axisY = event.values[1];
     float axisZ = event.values[2];

     // Calculate the angular speed of the sample
     float omegaMagnitude = (float) Math.sqrt(axisX*axisX + axisY*axisY + axisZ*axisZ);

     // Normalize the rotation vector if it's big enough to get the axis
     if (omegaMagnitude > EPSILON) {
         axisX /= omegaMagnitude;
         axisY /= omegaMagnitude;
         axisZ /= omegaMagnitude;
     }

     // Integrate around this axis with the angular speed by the timestep
     // in order to get a delta rotation from this sample over the timestep
     // We will convert this axis-angle representation of the delta rotation
     // into a quaternion before turning it into the rotation matrix.
     float thetaOverTwo = omegaMagnitude * dT / 2.0f;
     float sinThetaOverTwo = (float) Math.sin(thetaOverTwo);
     float cosThetaOverTwo = (float) Math.cos(thetaOverTwo);
     deltaRotationVector[0] = sinThetaOverTwo * axisX;
     deltaRotationVector[1] = sinThetaOverTwo * axisY;
     deltaRotationVector[2] = sinThetaOverTwo * axisZ;
     deltaRotationVector[3] = cosThetaOverTwo;
 }
 timestamp = event.timestamp;
 float[] deltaRotationMatrix = new float[9];
 SensorManager.getRotationMatrixFromVector(deltaRotationMatrix, deltaRotationVector);
 // User code should concatenate the delta rotation we computed with the current rotation
 // in order to get the updated rotation.
 // rotationCurrent = rotationCurrent * deltaRotationMatrix;
```

This code is taking from their documentation, is there anyway i could convert this to 360 degrees? or i could get values like how many degrees the phone was turned away from the starting point?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: pls check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18587262/get-quaternion-from-android-gyroscope

Answer (score 2):

Get the 3x3 rotation matrices, `R1` and `R2`, with [getRotationMatrix()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#getRotationMatrix%28float%5B%5D,%20float%5B%5D,%20float%5B%5D,%20float%5B%5D%29) at the two timepoints of interest. You would like to know the `angle` of the rotation `R` that brings `R1` to align with `R2`.

First calculate `R`:

```
R = R1 * transpose(R2)
```

Then calculate the angle of this rotation:

```
angle = acos((trace(R)-1)/2)
```

That is all.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking time to try answering this question. Im not a shark at mathematics. The RotationMatrix returned is not 2D, how to a transpose that? I made my own transpose method:   public float[] transposeMatrix(float[] m){
   float[] res = new float[9];
   res[0] = m[0];
   res[1] = m[3];
   res[2] = m[6];
   res[3] = m[1];
   res[4] = m[4];
   res[5] = m[7];
   res[6] = m[2];
   res[7] = m[5];
   res[8] = m[8]; 
   return m;  
   }

Comment: But however, im not able to * R1 and R2 in java, it says that the operater is undefined.

Any way you could give me a bit more help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Wikipedia is your friend: [transpose](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose#Examples) and [matrix multiplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Matrix_product_.28two_matrices.29).