# Get quaternion from Android gyroscope?

Tags: android, quaternions, gyroscope

[The official development documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion.html) suggests the following way of obtaining the quaternion from the 3D rotation rate vector `(wx, wy, wz)`.

```
// Create a constant to convert nanoseconds to seconds.
private static final float NS2S = 1.0f / 1000000000.0f;
private final float[] deltaRotationVector = new float[4]();
private float timestamp;

public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
  // This timestep's delta rotation to be multiplied by the current rotation
  // after computing it from the gyro sample data.
  if (timestamp != 0) {
    final float dT = (event.timestamp - timestamp) * NS2S;
    // Axis of the rotation sample, not normalized yet.
    float axisX = event.values[0];
    float axisY = event.values[1];
    float axisZ = event.values[2];

    // Calculate the angular speed of the sample
    float omegaMagnitude = sqrt(axisX*axisX + axisY*axisY + axisZ*axisZ);

    // Normalize the rotation vector if it's big enough to get the axis
    // (that is, EPSILON should represent your maximum allowable margin of error)
    if (omegaMagnitude > EPSILON) {
      axisX /= omegaMagnitude;
      axisY /= omegaMagnitude;
      axisZ /= omegaMagnitude;
    }

    // Integrate around this axis with the angular speed by the timestep
    // in order to get a delta rotation from this sample over the timestep
    // We will convert this axis-angle representation of the delta rotation
    // into a quaternion before turning it into the rotation matrix.
    float thetaOverTwo = omegaMagnitude * dT / 2.0f;
    float sinThetaOverTwo = sin(thetaOverTwo);
    float cosThetaOverTwo = cos(thetaOverTwo);
    deltaRotationVector[0] = sinThetaOverTwo * axisX;
    deltaRotationVector[1] = sinThetaOverTwo * axisY;
    deltaRotationVector[2] = sinThetaOverTwo * axisZ;
    deltaRotationVector[3] = cosThetaOverTwo;
  }
  timestamp = event.timestamp;
  float[] deltaRotationMatrix = new float[9];
  SensorManager.getRotationMatrixFromVector(deltaRotationMatrix, deltaRotationVector);
    // User code should concatenate the delta rotation we computed with the current rotation
    // in order to get the updated rotation.
    // rotationCurrent = rotationCurrent * deltaRotationMatrix;
   }
}
```

**My question is:**

It is quite **different from the acceleration case**, where computing the resultant acceleration using the accelerations **ALONG** the 3 axes makes sense.

I am really confused why the resultant rotation rate can also be computed with the sub-rotation rates **AROUND** the 3 axes. It does not make sense to me.

Why would this method - finding the **composite** rotation rate magnitude - even work?

Answer (score 21):

Since your title does not really match your questions, I'm trying to answer as much as I can.

Gyroscopes don't give an absolute orientation (as the [ROTATION_VECTOR](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion.html#sensors-motion-rotate)) but only rotational velocities around those axis they are built to 'rotate' around. This is due to the design and construction of a [gyroscope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gyroscope). Imagine the construction below. The golden thing is rotating and due to the [laws of physics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_of_inertia) it does not want to change its rotation. Now you can rotate the frame and measure these rotations.

[image: Illustration of a Gyroscope]

Now if you want to obtain something as the 'current rotational state' from the Gyroscope, you will have to start with an initial rotation, call it `q0` and constantly add those tiny little rotational differences that the gyroscope is measuring around the axis to it: `q1 = q0 + gyro0`, `q2 = q1 + gyro1`, ...

In other words: The Gyroscope gives you the difference it has rotated around the three constructed axis, so you are not composing absolute values but small deltas.

Now this is very general and leaves a couple of questions unanswered:

1. Where do I get an initial position from? Answer: Have a look at the Rotation Vector Sensor - you can use the Quaternion obtained from there as an initialisation
2. How to 'sum' q and gyro?

Depending on the current representation of a rotation: If you use a rotation matrix, a simple matrix multiplication should do the job, as suggested in the comments (note that this matrix-multiplication implementation is not efficient!):

```
/**
 * Performs naiv n^3 matrix multiplication and returns C = A * B
 * 
 * @param A Matrix in the array form (e.g. 3x3 => 9 values)
 * @param B Matrix in the array form (e.g. 3x3 => 9 values)
 * @return A * B
 */
public float[] naivMatrixMultiply(float[] B, float[] A) {
    int mA, nA, mB, nB;
    mA = nA = (int) Math.sqrt(A.length);
    mB = nB = (int) Math.sqrt(B.length);

    if (nA != mB)
        throw new RuntimeException("Illegal matrix dimensions.");

    float[] C = new float[mA * nB];
    for (int i = 0; i < mA; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < nB; j++)
            for (int k = 0; k < nA; k++)
                C[i + nA * j] += (A[i + nA * k] * B[k + nB * j]);
    return C;
}
```

To use this method, imagine that `mRotationMatrix` holds the current state, these two lines do the job:

```
SensorManager.getRotationMatrixFromVector(deltaRotationMatrix, deltaRotationVector);
mRotationMatrix = naivMatrixMultiply(mRotationMatrix, deltaRotationMatrix);
// Apply rotation matrix in OpenGL
gl.glMultMatrixf(mRotationMatrix, 0);
```

If you chose to use Quaternions, imagine again that `mQuaternion` contains the current state:

```
// Perform Quaternion multiplication
mQuaternion.multiplyByQuat(deltaRotationVector);
// Apply Quaternion in OpenGL
gl.glRotatef((float) (2.0f * Math.acos(mQuaternion.getW()) * 180.0f / Math.PI),mQuaternion.getX(),mQuaternion.getY(), mQuaternion.getZ());
```

Quaternion multiplication is described [here - equation (23)](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Quaternion.html). Make sure, you apply the multiplication correctly, since it is not commutative!

If you want to simply know rotation of your device (I assume this is what you ultimately want) I strongly recommend the ROTATION_VECTOR-Sensor. On the other hand Gyroscopes are quite precise for measuring rotational velocity and have a very good dynamic response, but suffer from drift and don't give you an absolute orientation (to magnetic north or according to gravity).

**UPDATE**: If you want to see a full example, you can download the source-code for a simple [demo-app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.hitlabnz.sensor_fusion_demo) from https://bitbucket.org/apacha/sensor-fusion-demo.

Comment: can you please help me here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24242972/how-can-i-get-device-tilt

Comment: The picture of a gimbal gyro is misleading because that gyroscope does measure orientation. If you rotate along a gimbal axis at a constant speed, the corresponding gimbal axis will rotate at the same speed. If you read out the gimbal angles, those will literally be Euler angles, subject to the singularity which is sometimes called "gimbal lock" exactly because of this picture.

MEMS gyros in your phone don't look like this and they do indeed measure angular velocity.

Comment: How to perform quaternion multiplication in android?

Comment: A link to the equation is given. You can also check out my implementation at https://bitbucket.org/apacha/sensor-fusion-demo/src/5a48a7cbdad4ce88591eb581259d3f340d9d5437/app/src/main/java/org/hitlabnz/sensor_fusion_demo/representation/Quaternion.java?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default

Answer (score 0):

Makes sense to me. Acceleration sensors typically work by having some measurable quantity change when force is applied to the axis being measured. E.g. if gravity is pulling down on the sensor measuring that axis, it conducts electricity better. So now you can tell how hard gravity, or acceleration in some direction, is pulling. Easy.

Meanwhile gyros are things that spin (OK, or bounce back and forth in a straight line like a tweaked diving board). The gyro is spinning, now you spin, the gyro is going to look like it is spinning faster or slower depending on the direction you spun. Or if you try to move it, it will resist and try to keep going the way it is going. So you just get a rotation change out of measuring it. Then you have to figure out the force from the change by integrating all the changes over the amount of time.

Typically none of these things are one sensor either. They are often 3 different sensors all arranged perpendicular to each other, and measuring a different axis. Sometimes all the sensors are on the same chip, but they are still different things on the chip measured separately.

Comment: Thanks for the time to answer it, but it seems not to have answered my question...

Comment: The problem is that your question is why gyros don't act like linear force sensors. The answer is that they are not the same thing. Gyros spin (or vibrate with horizontal force away from the vibration measured as a hack). That's why all gyro measurements are based on rotation and not linear force along an axis. The entire comment is trying to explain to you what each thing is and how they are different. Why do you think you could measure anything other than rotation off a gyro?