# Isn't it possible for Unity to get Quaternion data from Android?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, quaternions

I'm trying to send from Android Quaternion data to quaternion.

When I send (X,Y,Z) and use Quaternion from unity reference, it works, but when send Quaternion data, it doesn't work.

I think unity didn't get the quaternion data(x,y,z,w) from Android, is that right?

Comment: Please, read tag descriptions before using them.

Comment: What does "send quaternion data to quaternion" even mean?

Comment: Do you mean the rotation data from the gyroscope?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18587262/get-quaternion-from-android-gyroscope